# Prove that the function $\frac{f^2(t)-1}{t^2}$ is smooth at $t=0$ implies that $f^{(1)}(0)=f^{(3)}(0)=\dots=f^{(\mathrm{odd})}(0)=0$

Tags: calculus

My textbook says the following:

> Let us assume that the function $f(t)$ has a Taylor expansion, and that $f(0)=1$. Then the function $$\frac{f^2(t)-1}{t^2}$$ is smooth at $t=0$ implies that $f^{(1)}(0)=f^{(3)}(0)=\dots=f^{(\mathrm{odd})}(0)=0$.

How do I prove this? I could prove that $f^{(1)}(0)=0$ by simply expanding out the numerator and dividing by $t^2$. However, I cannot prove the rest of the conditions.

Comment: What does $f^2(t)$ stand for? Also, what is the value of $f(0)$?

Comment: @SangchulLee- That just refers to f squared. Also, $f(0)=1$.

Comment: *Hint.* Note that we may write $$f(x)^2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$ near $0$, where $$a_n = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}(0)f^{(n-k)}(0).$$ Now check that (1) $a_0 = 1$ and $a_n = 0$ for all *odd* $n$, and (2) $$ \frac{f(x)^{2}-1}{x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{2k+2}x^{2k}.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee- I don't think that's the expression for $a_n$ that we get....? And how does one see that $a_n=0$ without assuming that $f^{(odd)}(0)=0$?

Comment: @SangchulLee- I suppose that my phrasing was confusing. I have now re phrased the question

Comment: The expression for $a_n$ follows from rearranging the double sum $$\sum_{a,b=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(a)}(0)}{a!}{f^{(b)}(0)}{b!}x^{a+b}$$ in terms of the exponent of $x$, or more systematically, using the Cauchy product. Now, the new version of your question is simply false. Indeed, if a function $f$ is analytic near $0$, then $(f(x)^2-1)/x^2$ is also analytic (or more precisely, can be continuated at $0$ to give an analytic function) near $0$ if and only if $f(0) = 1$ and $f'(0)=0$.